# Php return after x seconds

Tags: php, delay

I have a php function that should finish running well under **x** seconds.

I won’t allow one IP to run the script multiple times. Even this small delay will prevent easy spamming and require a more distributed attack to overrun my web server.

Another (perhaps more significant) potential for this feature is to prevent against timing attacks. If all time variation can be removed from the script (start async task, begin counting, return whatever’s ready from async task when time reached), than time cannot be used as a variable to exploit. This would be particularly beneficial to me as I want a slowed execution anyway.

How can I (with max precision available) run a routine after a set delay in php? I imagine the exact implementation of this will determine the feasibility of using this method against timing attacks as well as generic delay.

Comment: `I won’t allow one IP to run the script multiple times` .... how? Since the web server handles instantiations

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to clarify what you're actually after here. From what I understand your intention and overall goal is to prevent abuse of the system. This is achievable by preventing too many requests from overwhelming the system.

However, to achieve this you don't need to delay the execution of a routine. Rather what is easier to do, and more sensible, is to simply stop the request from executing the routine if it has exceeded a maximum usage criteria within a given amount of time.

This is otherwise known as **rate limiting**.

Rate limiting can be easily achieved by storing the IP or user id in memcached or redis (or any key/value store or database really) along with a timestamp of when the last successful attempt occurred. This way a check against the current timestamp and the stored timestamp results in a decision to either allow or deny the routine from executing.

As an example, let's say we want to only allow each IP address to make at most 1 request every 15 seconds.

```
// check if a successful attempt has already occurred in the last 15 seconds
$ts = $memcached->get($ip);
if (time() - $ts <= 15) { // attempt exceeds rate limit
    echo "Request denied. You've exceeded your rate limit!";
} else { // attempt does not exceed rate limit
    $memcached->set($ip, time()); // store the timestamp of last successful attempt
    doRoutine(); // OK to proceed
}
```